# In backbone, can same views in different collections merge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have three collections that have an identical index view, by using identical I mean they have the same template content in different folders, the same events,the same initialize parameters and render method, it's just that the index view was loaded using different collections.So is there a way to merge them?

Comment: You have three collections (all instances of the same `C = Backbone.Collection.extend(...)`) and each has a view that is an instance of the same `V = Backbone.View.extend(...)` and you want to end up with one `C` and how many `V`s?

Comment: I want one V that can be applied by 3 Cs.

Comment: So just do it, what is the problem? I suppose, the only restriction is in your head because of the view (variable) names.

Comment: You see, I just don't know how to render index using different collections, I assume that it was done by router,so I just need to change my collections routers to render the same index view,is that correct?